# dd oflag=direct 5x fast

Tags: centos, performance, raid, dd

I have Centos 6.2 in server with this specs:

```
2xCPU 16 Core AMD Opteron 6282 SE
64GB RAM
Raid controller H700 1GB cache NV
- 2HD 74GB SAS 15Krpm RAID1 stripe 16k (OS Centos 6.2) sda
- 4HD 146GB SAS 15Krpm RAID10 stripe 16k (ext4 bs 4096, no barriers) sdb -> /vol01
Raid controller H800 1GB cache nv
- MD1200 12HD 300GB SAS 15Krpm RAID10 stripe 256k (For DB Postgres 8.3.18) (ext4 bs 4096, stride 64, stripe-width 384, no barriers) sdc -> /vol02
```

I'm benchmarking IO speed with dd, and view thah if in RAID10 12 disk exec:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=DD bs=8M count=10000 oflag=direct
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
83886080000 bytes (84 GB) copied, 126,03 s, 666 MB/s
```

but if I remove "oflag=direct" option obtain about **80 MB/s**.
In read benchmark, results are similar:

```
dd of=/dev/null if=DD bs=8M count=10000 iflag=direct
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
83886080000 bytes (84 GB) copied, 79,5918 s, 1,1 GB/s
```

If remove iflag=direct obtain **150MB/s**...

I don't understand this huge differences, on other machines y don't have this behavior.

Can I have some kernel parameter misconfigured?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't test with if=/dev/zero, some newer controllers figure out the pattern and will mess with your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Finally the problem was Bios misconfiguration.
I have set "Power Management" to "Maximum Performance" profile on BIOS:
[DELL best practices in power management](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/power-cooling/w/wiki/best-practices-in-power-management.aspx)

With this setting, dd has the same performance with or without oflag=direct